# How to make a custom proc in a class so I can do: params_hash.downcase_keys instead of downcase_keys(params_hash)?

Tags: ruby, lambda, functional-programming, proc

I have a hash of key values and I want to downcase all of the Keys.
However I don't want to have to create an local variable, I would rather functionally do it.

NOT: 
`x = downcase_keys(params_hash)`

BUT THIS:
`params_hash.downcase_keys`

How would do this in ruby?

Comment: Also, would like to have it encapsulated within a class.

Comment: Why do you want to use a proc/lambda. Just define a method (with `def`)?

Comment: Just trying to avoid local varaibles.

Comment: `h.transform_keys(&:downcase)` - Ruby 2.5+ or Rails. 2.5+ will give you the speed benefit of C-compiled function calls. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why you tagged this question as `functional-programming` it seems you are looking for a method to call on a `Hash` object.

Be aware that you may encounter problems doing so because duplicated keys are going to be overwritten.

```
h = {"a" => 1, "B" => 2}

# Singleton method on the object
def h.downcase_keys
  temp = map {|k,v| [k.downcase, v]}.to_h
  clear
  merge! temp
end

h.downcase_keys()
p h  # {"a"=>1, "b"=>2}

 # Method available on all Hash objects
class Hash
  def downcase_keys
    temp = map {|k,v| [k.downcase, v]}.to_h
    clear
    merge! temp
  end
end

h = {"a" => 1, "B" => 2}
h.downcase_keys()
p h # {"a"=>1, "b"=>2}

def downcase_keys(hash)
  hash.downcase_keys
end

h = {"C" => 1, "B" => 2, "D" => 3}
downcase_keys(h)
p h # {"c"=>1, "b"=>2, "d"=>3}
```